# How to get to /public outside WEB-INF when using Spring MVC

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat, spring-mvc, document-root

i'm having hard time uploading images to public folder.The public folder is a sibbling of WEB-INF inside Webapp folder.

attempts like 
    `this.getClass().getResource("/images/16x16").toString()` returns null pointer exception.

i've added image folder as resource

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/public/images/" />
```

is there a way to achieve that? thanks for reading this

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't consider the webapp's folder is accessible to write file. The app could be deployed as a war file, and if you redeploy the app, you'll loase all the uploaded files. Store the uploaded files elsewhere.

Second, `Class.getResource()` loads resources from the classpath. It doesn't load from the file system or the webapp's context. `Class.getResource()` will only find resources stored in WEB-INF/classes, in one of the jars of WEB-INF/lib, or in a jar of the container's classpath.

If you need to load something from the webapp's context (which you shouldn't do in this case), use [ServletContext.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) (or `getResourceAsStream()`)

Comment: i get the point.let's say my app is runing under /usr/local/tomcat/myaqpp .if i store the image under something /home/myaccountname/images showing them in a file would be loading them from their absolute path. am i right?

Comment: Yes, you would use File IO to load the image.